# JNI IsSameObject method returns wrong value in Android 13

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

The purpose is to compare a byte array against the NULL value

```
jmethodID midGet = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, classArrayList, "get", "(I)Ljava/lang/Object;");
jbyteArray arr = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, arrayList, midGet, 0);
if (!(*env)->IsSameObject(env, arr, NULL)) {
    // Always falls in here when testing with Android 13
    // For Android <13, this block is not executed
}
```

arrayList is passed in from Java layer

```
ArrayList<byte[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(null);
```

The IsSameObject method returns unexpected value in Android 13. Please help me figure out. Thanks!

Comment: Are there perhaps pending exceptions on the stack? In particular, have you enabled the checking JNI layer to make sure everything else is okay?

Comment: Reinforcing what @Botje stated:  if `arrayList` is `NULL` in your posted code, `(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, arrayList, midGet, 0);` is going to throw a `NullPointerException`.  You can't call an object method on a `null` object.

Comment: arrayList is not NULL, the first element of the arrayList is NULL

Comment: Another unlikely guess: did somebody change the definition of the NULL macro from under you? The Android JNI implementation checks for equality to a `nullptr` of the right type.

Comment: We have checked that, we don't see any modifications